# Is it possible to create an array that is shared between classes in swift?

Tags: swift, swiftui, struct

I am looking to create a list of objects that will be edited or accessed by multiple different classes in different ways, is this possible to do without having to pass the array as a parameter between classes?

I have

```
var list: [myObject]

func createObject( list: inout [myObject], objectName: String, objectType: Int){
    var newObject = myObject (objectName: objectName, objectType: objectType)
    list.append(newObject)
}
```

which in theory creates an empty list of objects and then every time I'd call the function would add a new object to the list.

Comment: Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app: 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app). It has a specific example using an array.

Comment: This is called "shared mutable state," and the past 20 or so years of programming language design has basically tried its best to eliminate it where possible. "Everything is shared and conveniently updated" _seems_ really convenient, but comes with a brutal downside: your values can magically change because of some unrelated code, and you have no easy way to track down why. Swift's `Array` expressly goes out of its way to _not_ let you accidentally share it, by creating a copy anytime you try to write to a shared array.

Comment: What you mostly likely want instead is a new class, whose instances store a private array. You can make one main object of this class, and pass out references to it, to whoever might need to listen to its changes, or make changes to it. Importantly, you should not let people directly modify the array. Instead, expose meaningful methods that let you subscribe for changes as you see fit.

Comment: Swift or SwiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have one central array that mutates as your various classes make changes to it, create a class to serve as your app's "model", or data store. Provide methods that the other classes can call to make changes to your array. (The code you posted could be a start to the model class.)